# Commerce Extra Pane wont drag in checkout UI

Tags: commerce

I have created a Drupal Commerce pane using the [Commerce Extra Panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_panes) module. I created a group and field and they show up on the UI. However, its listed in the Disabled section. I tried to drag it into the Checkout pane and when I save it reverts back to the Disabled section.

When I look in the database it does list it correctly in the Checkout pane, but it doesn't actually appear on any page pane.

What is happening here and what can I do to debug more?

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit odd, but the only thing I can come up without more information is that you might have the node disabled in the commerce extra panes tab:

[image]

If that's not the case, try also to disable the js in the checkout configuration form, click on "show row weights" so you can select the page for each pane without dragging and dropping.

[image]